# What does git fsck stand for?

Tags: git, git-fsck

What is the meaning in behind the `fsck` command name?

The [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck) of the command does not seem to mention what the name stands for.

Comment: When you are going to use `fsck` it's because things are **really** messed up, but they can't swear in git commands  so they replaced a vowel with an `s`

Answer (score 79, accepted):

It stands for File System ChecK. The name is taken from the Unix [`fsck`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/fsck) command, which is used to validate a file system.

While Git is not technically a file system, it can be used analogously and the command name is a metaphor on this.

Comment: @LopSae, note that Git originally was envisioned as a versioned file system, and only subsequently grew into a full-fledged DVCS.

Comment: I had to scroll down to the other answer, which does a bit better job in explaining it. This answer is no good.

Comment: Git was not in fact ever a file system, as it required one to function, but rather a DVCS made from the perspective of a file system, which made it much fasyer

Comment: @circl True, but like many computer-related terms, it's metaphorical.

Answer (score 40):

It was first called:

- [`fsck-cached`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/20222118ae4cbd0a7ba91a7012574cd2f91101ec) (git 0.99), to check the repository for errors
- then [`fsck-objects`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f1f0d0889e5557bc467490fdbd53f7b912503a33) (git 0.99.8), in order to report what exactly is wrong with the object, instead of an ambiguous 'bad sha1 file'.
- and finally [`git fsck`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/df391b192d285646fe80ca4d3cfe3c0a3beb5989) (git 1.5.0, January 2007)

It reflects that Git was initially built as a file system, with a graph of nodes and [`git fsck`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck) is presented in this [GitHub Training](http://training.github.com/articles/lesson-git-repo-maintenance/) as a **file system check** which verifies integrity and finds corrupt objects.