# How to add particular changes using gulp

Tags: javascript, git, gulp

Will explain what am looking to achieve.
Created a sample gulp file using git am able to fetch and push the changes into git.

For example if am having a file called as abc.js, If am doing any changes in that file then using the gulp git it replacing the abc.js file with the changed version of abc.js.

Instead of this is there any way just to push only the changed content instead of entire file.

Can anyone let me know how to achieve...

More deeply:

Default abc.js:

```
function sample(){
alert('hai');alert('bye');
}
```

Changed abc.js:

```
function sample(){
alert('bye');
}
```

How to just remove the alert('hai') only instead of pushing entire file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is something that git will manage it self. Git will store deltas, so when you are pushing, actually git internally will push only the delta. If I did understood you properly, what you want is actually the default behavior of git and you don't have to worry about that.

Check this link too about how git works: [How does git store files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198105/how-does-git-store-files)

Comment: I posted a question can you please help me out...       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24858702/how-to-add-del-dependency-in-gulp