# How to add 'del' dependency in gulp

Tags: gulp

New to gulp, need to add the dependency 'del'.

I have seen this delete dependency but unable to found the npm installation for this 'del'.
If directly tried to access

`var del = require('del');`

It throws error unable to find the module.

Can anyone help out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you installed it?

```
npm install --save-dev del
```

https://www.npmjs.org/package/del