# Where do files of one branch go when I checkout to another branch?

Tags: git, memory, github, bitbucket, git-bash

I have a git repository at `G:\C\BIT`. It has two branches `dev` and `master`. `master` is empty and `dev` has three follders `A`, `B`, and `C`. Now when I am in `dev` branch then these folders show in computer. But when I checkout to `master` branch all the three folders `A`, `B` and `C` become invisible. Not only they are invisible but they don't take space on my hardisk too. `G:\C\BIT` in `dev` is 4 MB and in `master` 2.75 MB. My question is

- Where do files of one branch go when I checkout to another branch? Are they hard deleted and then redownloaded when I checkout to the former branch again?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198105/how-does-git-store-files

Answer (score 3):

Your git repository is stored in the `.git` directory of your working directory.  When you check out a new branch, files may be added or deleted from your working directory, but they remain untouched in the git repository.

Git only operates on local files; while it has facilities for synchronization changes to and from remote repositories, actions like checking out a file or committing changes only affect the local repository.

Comment: To add to this answer it may be an interesting exercise for the OP to check the space taken up by the .git directory - it should show that the .git directory accounts for a significant and consistent portion of the 4MB and 2.75MB figures.

Comment: Seems like this is exactly what is happening. there is a lot of data stored in `.git/objects` folder. And the data seems to be encrypted. Thanks.

Comment: @haggisandchips I just pasted a 300MB folder in repository with `dev` branch checked. Now when I switched to `master `.git` is 300 MB.