# Does a new commit include changes from old commit?

Tags: git, git-commit

Lets say  I have a local repository named 'ABC" having a text file.
I add 2 lines to the text file, and commit it. Lets call it "Commit A". 
Then I add 2 more lines to it and commit it. Lets call it "Commit B".

Will Commit B have the original text in text file and all the 4 new lines added, or just the 2 lines added in Commit B?

If I branch from Commit B, will the new branch have the original text and the 4 lines added, or just the 2 lines added in Commit B?

Comment: as far as im aware, when you commit a change, it updates your local repository. so making further changes/commits will update it relative to the previous state of the file

Comment: You probably should think of a commit as a complete snapshot of your working directory. It is efficiently stored, but should not be your concern. If you want to dig deeper you can start with [Git Objects](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Internals-Git-Objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In layman terms, a commit is like a change set or a snapshot of your repo. Please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40617288/a-commit-in-git-is-it-a-snapshot-state-image-or-is-it-a-change-diff-patch-delta) for more details.

In your example, when you checkout a branch from Commit B, the branch will have commit B and its all past commits. Hence the new branch will have original text and 4 lines added.

Comment: A commit is a snapshot. Not a change set.