# Why is it so slow to delete a folder that contains .git repository?

Tags: git, performance, repository, delete-file, slowdown

I think the best way to delete a repository is to first delete the ".git" hidden folder then, if needed remove other files and direcotories. But, why removing all in once take so long ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, git stores *all* revisions of your code, that means, each time you do a commit git copy the whole project somewhere under `.git/`.

Knowing that, you will easily understand how it could become long to remove this folder.

Here is a pretty good SO post about that: [How does git store files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198105/how-does-git-store-files)