# What database does Git use for metadata and how can I access it?

Tags: git

`git log` is a powerful Git command which allows to make queries on a lot of things: file authors, commit description, commit dates etc. Git itself [says](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics) that metadata is stored in some database. I wasn't able to find what kind of database anywhere.

So I'm wondering what is this database? Is it relational and perhaps I can  somehow use SQL in order to perform the queries directly from the database instead of using `git log`?

EDIT: this question is different from [How does git store files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198105/how-does-git-store-files) because that question mainly asks about how Git stores committed files while my question asks about metadata storage (metadata != data).

Comment: Why would you like to do so ? There are plenty of libraries to work with git in your favourited programming language

Comment: @gogaz because it will be easier for me to perform complicated queries in SQL rather than using multiple git flags. Also I'm genuinely interested how Git saves the metadata

Comment: Git uses compressed files basically, the repository is a combination of metadata-objects and blobs (the actual file versions). The metadata objects are just compressed text files. So there is no SQL database at all. You're best off using a library for it, like libgit2 which is available for many runtimes and languages.

Comment: Just to take an example, if you create a new repository, create a file, add the file to the index, then commit it, your "database" consists of the commit object (compressed text), a tree object (directory structure, compressed text) and the file blob, as 3 separate files, all under .git\objects

Comment: So it's not a database in your traditional sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does git store files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198105/how-does-git-store-files)

Comment: Specifically, it is a simple key-value store with the keys being hash IDs. The values stored under these keys are one of four value types: *annotated tag*, *commit*, *tree*, and *blob*. The first three have in their values fields that are defined to contain more keys and the entire set of values always forms a Directed Acyclic Graph or DAG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that description, Git describes its internal state as a "database" in the most literal sense of the word. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database):

> A database is an organized collection of data, stored and accessed electronically.

It is not a relational database, or one you can easily query using a query language such as SQL.

You can however access the database programatically. For example using [LibGit2Sharp](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp) and Linq, if you're on .NET:

```
using (var repo = new Repository(@"path\to\repo.git"))
{
    // Rev walking
    var commits = repo.Commits
                      .StartingAt("sha")
                      .Where(c => c.Author.Email.Contains("@example.com"))
                      .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the `git glossary` (at https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary)

> **object database** - Stores a set of "objects", and an individual object is identified by its object name. The objects usually live in $GIT_DIR/objects/.

The database is the collection of files typically stored under `.git/objects/` (or, for a bare repo, just `objects/`).

This is not an RDBMS.  It has no general-purpose query language, but rather it's designed to work with various git tools (and vice versa) to enable fast access to the information git needs.