# How does git work on a technical level to allow a single file to exist in two states at once?

Tags: git, macos, github

I am very new to git and github and am trying to wrap my head around all the different functionalities of this program.

I am currently exploring making new branches in my local repo, pushing those branches to my remote repo, and switching between branches in my local repo, and I've encountered a property that is both confusing but really interesting, and I was hoping someone could offer some clarification as to how this property works.

I am working with a single html file. On my local repo, I created a new branch, I checked out the branch, and I opened this file within the branch and made some edits. Then, I went back to my other branch, opened up the same file, and as expected, the edits I made were not there (since they exist on the other branch, and not the one I am currently on). I understand this on a conceptual level (you make changes to a file on one branch, obviously these changes won't be present on the other branch unless you merge them). BUT, what I am confused by is that on my machine, I only have a single copy of this file... but somehow this file simultaneously exists as two different versions on my machine. It's a property that once again, I understand on an abstract level, but I would appreciate an explanation of how files can have this property.

Comment: You might find [this article](https://maryrosecook.com/blog/post/git-from-the-inside-out), [this article](https://wyag.thb.lt/) and/or [this article](http://gitlet.maryrosecook.com/docs/gitlet.html) useful

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8198276/7976758 found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+how+does+store+files

Comment: And my favorite [how it works article](https://tom.preston-werner.com/2009/05/19/the-git-parable.html)

Answer (score 4):

> on my machine, I only have a single copy of this file

But you don't.

Git remembers *all* the versions of the file (`git add` literally adds a snapshot to the repository) and it puts whichever one you want to see in your filesystem at the expected place on demand.

Comment: And it's worth pointing out that git *logically* stores every version of every file, but *physically* it does a lot of optimization behind the scenes. If it actually stored full copies of every version, it would be impractical.

Comment: True enough, it starts with full snapshots and compresses in stages, cheap-n-prettygood zlib compression on add, and when it looks like there's big wins available it'll `git repack` with some industrial-strength compression including lots scope for finding deltas from history (not just the previous version, and not just that one file).

Answer (score 0):

As [jthill said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61990903/1256452), your *working tree* or *work-tree* has only one copy of the file.  Git has, in its commits, *every* copy of the file: each commit has one copy of each file.  The copies are de-duplicated, in a clever manner that depends on the fact that nothing in Git, once committed, can *ever* be changed.  So the files inside commits are frozen for all time, along with the rest of the commit (there's a bit of stuff besides just the files).

More precisely, each commit has a full snapshot of the files that you had told Git to put *into* that commit, at the time you made that commit.  Or, if it wasn't you that made the commit, insert some other actor as the person invoking Git commands.

These committed files *are* in the repository, contained by right of being stored inside each commit.  But the files that *you* see and work with, in your work-tree, *are not in Git at all*.  I think it helps, conceptually, if you think of the work-tree files as *yours:* you are responsible for these files.  The files in commits—the ones in each commit snapshot, made when you or whoever ran `git commit`—are the responsibility of Git.

Once you have this in your head—that Git is just copying one set of *its* files out of a commit, over top of *your* files—a lot of things fall into place.  The remaining rather large surprise is that in an important way, *branches* don't matter.  What matters in Git are, always, the *commits*.  The *branch names* like `master` or `develop` are just one way of *finding* specific commits.

When you clone a repository, or use `git push` or `git fetch`,<sup>1</sup> you're asking your Git to connect to some other Git.  So there are multiple copies of each repository. These repositories share *commits*—by copying them—but they need not share their *branch names* at all.  That's OK, because it's the *commits* that matter, not the branch names.

---

<sup>1</sup>Don't think of `git pull` as the opposite of `git fetch`, because it's not.  Think of fetch and push as the two opposites.  Well, ok: they're *as close as Git gets* to opposites here.  Mercurial got this particular terminology right (in Mercurial, pull does what fetch does in Git) and Git just sort of got it backwards.

---

#### Branch names don't matter, except to humans

The real name of a commit is its hash ID.  To see the hash ID of some commit, use `git rev-parse`, whose job is to turn a name into a hash ID:<sup>2</sup>

```
$ git rev-parse master
b994622632154fc3b17fb40a38819ad954a5fb88
$ git rev-parse origin/maint
af6b65d45ef179ed52087e80cb089f6b2349f4ec
```

These hash IDs are how Git finds commits—at least, some specific commit that we humans might care about right now.  The *name* `master` is specifically a *branch name*, while the names `origin/maint` or `origin/master` aren't branch names.  But all of these names locate some commit.  Sometimes, more than one name locates the *same* commit:

```
$ git rev-parse origin/master
b994622632154fc3b17fb40a38819ad954a5fb88
```

This is the *same hash ID* that I got for my `master` here.  That's no coincidence: the Git repository I cloned has a `master` branch, and the last time I talked with that Git repository—a few weeks ago at this point—they had *their* `master` set up to remember commit `b994622632154fc3b17fb40a38819ad954a5fb88`.  So I told *my* Git that *it* should remember `b994622632154fc3b17fb40a38819ad954a5fb88` under *my* name `master`, too.

Whenever you use branch names in Git, you're telling Git: *Remember this commit hash ID under this name.*  The special property of a *branch name*—different from a *remote-tracking name* like `origin/master`,<sup>3</sup> for instance—is that if you use `git switch` or `git checkout` to select its commit, something special happens:

```
$ git switch dev
Switched to branch 'dev'
$ git switch master
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
```

If you pick a non-branch name, `git switch` complains while `git checkout` puts you into *detached HEAD* mode:

```
$ git switch origin/master
fatal: a branch is expected, got remote branch 'origin/master'
$ git checkout origin/master
Note: switching to 'origin/master'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
...
HEAD is now at b994622632 The eighth batch
```

Note that `git switch`, which is a more-user-friendly command, allows you to get into detached HEAD mode the same way, but only *on purpose:* you have to add `--detach` to the command.  Detached HEAD mode has its uses, but everyday work is not one of them, so it's wise to get back in a branch, for your own mental health:

```
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
```

and we're back in the happier state in which *Git* will remember hash IDs for us, using our branch names.  If you don't have *Git* remember them for you, *you* will have to memorize these hash IDs, and that is no fun at all.

---

<sup>2</sup>Well, that's *one* of its jobs.  Git has a tendency to load too many jobs into too-few commands.  That's why Git 2.23 and later have `git switch` and `git restore`, while earlier versions of Git jam both commands into `git checkout`.

<sup>3</sup>About these `origin/*` names: `git switch` calls `origin/master` a *remote branch*, but that is a terrible name.  Git documentation calls it a *remote-tracking branch name*, which is slightly better.  I use the phrase *remote-tracking name*, to try to get away from the word *branch*, which is way too overused in Git.  The real key here is to remember that while it's a *name*, it's not a *branch* name in the sense that you can't `git switch` to it.

---

#### Commits remember previous commit hash IDs

The last piece to this particular puzzle is a clever (and/or sneaky) trick.  If a commit has a hash ID—and it does—and if that hash ID is how Git *finds* the commit—and it is—then what happens if we have every *new* commit we make, remember the raw hash ID of the commit that comes *just before* it?

That is, suppose we have a string of commits like this, except that they have real hash IDs instead of single uppercase letters:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

Here `H` stands in for the real hash ID of the *latest* commit.  Let's have Git remember the actual hash ID, using the *branch name* `master`, like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--master
```

We say that the *name* `master` *points to* commit `H`.  But we told Git, when we made `H`, that Git should have commit `H` remember the hash ID of commit `G`!  So given that we're working with commit `H` right now, Git can just look up the hash ID of `G` *using commit `H` itself*.  Commit `H` *points to* earlier commit `G`.

Of course, earlier commit `G` points to even-earlier commit `F`, and so on, all the way back to the very first commit.  That commit doesn't point backwards, because it can't, so that's where Git gets to stop and rest.  Otherwise, if you start Git with the name `master`, Git will find `H`, then use that to find `G` and then `F` and `E` and so on all the way back to the first commit `A`:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
```

which is our repository with eight total commits, all in one line.

#### Branches

Let's say we have this structure at the moment:

```
...--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
```

If we now create a new *branch name*, but let it signify commit `H` too, we get:

```
...--G--H   <-- dev, master (HEAD)
```

We can now attach the special name `HEAD` to either branch name.  It doesn't matter which *name* we use because both mean *commit `H`:* the files we see in our work-tree will be the same either way.  But let's switch to `dev`, with `git switch dev` or `git checkout dev`:

```
...--G--H   <-- dev (HEAD), master
```

Now let's make a *new* commit, in the usual way.<sup>4</sup>  This new commit gets a new, unique hash ID, which is big and ugly and unpredictable;<sup>5</sup> but let's just call it `I`.

New commit `I` automatically points back to existing commit `H`:

```
...--G--H
         \
          I
```

and now Git pulls its really-sneaky trick: `git commit` *writes the new hash ID into the **name** `dev`*, because that's the name `HEAD` is attached-to.  So the *branch name `dev` **moves***, giving us:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I   <-- dev (HEAD)
```

Note how the *name* `master` still selects commit `H`, while the *name* `dev` now selects commit `I`.  If we make another new commit here we get:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J   <-- dev (HEAD)
```

Git will now find commit `J` using the name `dev`, and find commit `I` using commit `J`.  Git has *two ways* to find commit `H`: the name `master` finds it directly, and `dev` finds it after traversing two hops backwards, from `J` to `I` to `H`.

In Git, the commits up through `H` are on *both branches*.  Commits `I` and `J` are only on `dev`.  If `I` and/or `J` contain files that `H` doesn't, switching from `dev` back to `master` will *remove* these files from **your** work-tree: you told Git *set up **my** work-tree based on commit `H`*, and it does that.  Switching from `master` to `dev` brings the files back, because you told Git: *set up **my** work-tree based on commit `J`.*

If we go back to commit `H` and create and switch to a new *name* `topic`, we get:

```
...--G--H   <-- master, topic (HEAD)
         \
          I--J   <-- dev
```

and now we can create new commits as usual:

```
          I--J   <-- dev
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          K--L   <-- topic (HEAD)
```

---

<sup>4</sup>I've just glossed completely over the complicated way Git makes new commits, which involves Git's *index*.  I won't go into details in this answer, though.

<sup>5</sup>Technically, if we know:

- what source files, exactly, will be in the snapshot (all their names and contents);
- what *metadata* you'll give Git—your name, email address, and so on, *and* the log message you will use; *and*
- the hash ID `H` and the exact date and time at which you will make new commit `I`;

*then* we could predict what the actual hash ID of commit `I` will be.  But how will we predict *all* of these?  So we might as well think of `I` as being "random".

---

#### Draw graphs!

I flipped `dev` to the top row just so that the "bigger letters" `K` and `L` would be on the bottom.  You can draw the graph any number of ways, as long as the *connections from commit to commit*, the backwards links from `J` to `I` and the like, are still drawn and as long as you label the correct commits with the correct names.  You can leave out some names, and some commits—like the ones before `G`—when they just clutter up the drawing.

Whatever you do, though, it's really good exercise to draw a bunch of graphs—on paper, on a whiteboard, or whatever.  When you do this you'll notice things, like:

- Branch *names* find the *last* commit in a chain.  Git calls this the *tip commit* of the branch.
- The arrows all go *backwards*.  Git has to start at the end, and work backwards.
- If a chain has no *name* for its last commit, Git can't find any of it.

Knowing these things leaves you in a good position for learning all the other mysteries of Git, such as how `git merge` and `git rebase` work.

Comment: Okay first question as I read through this -- you say not to think of git fetch and git push as opposites; actually, that's not what comes to mind when I think of opposites. I think of git push and git pull as being opposites. Is this accurate? Also what is the difference between fetch and pull?

Comment: Second question -- I see that you really don't like the term branch, and it is really interesting to learn that branches don't really matter. But, it is confusing to me, because I thought the point of a branch was to store a sequence of commits which differ from another sequence of commits. And also, isn't it possible to create an empty branch? If so, is an empty branch basically just a hash number that acts like a vacant space for future commits?

Comment: Third question - you say that "We can now attach the special name HEAD to either branch name. It doesn't matter which name we use because both mean commit H: the files we see in our work-tree will be the same either way." but the files we see won't be the same -- we will see the copy of the file in branch A, and if we switch to branch B, we will see the branch B file copy. Correct? Or is a new file copy only created after a commit? So File A on Branch A exists, then we create Branch B; is a new file copy created at this time? Or is Branch B just a name now associated with file A?

Comment: 1: Fetch and push are as as close as Git gets to opposites. The Mercurial command `hg pull` is spelled `git fetch` in Git, and the Mercurial command `hg push` is spelled `git push` in Git. So in Mercurial, the two words are used correctly. But in Git, `git pull` means *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command*. There is no second Git command with `git push`. So that's where Git went wrong in assigning *meanings* to the two words, and is why `fetch`, not `pull`, is the opposite of `push`.

Comment: 2: It's not so much that I don't like the term, as that the word itself, in Git, is ambiguous. Different people use the same word to mean different things, and thereby confuse each other. One person will use the same word to mean up to three different things. Imagine you're at a party and everyone's name is Bruce. Bruce tells you that Bruce went to fetch Bruce, who's with Bruce at Bruce's house, but Bruce is in the kitchen if you're looking for Bruce. Who did what? Who is where? (And no, there's no such thing as an empty branch in Git, regardless of which of the meanings you use.)

Comment: 3: No, there's only one *committed* copy of the file: it is in commit H. If name A refers to H, and name B refers to H, you can use either *name* and you get the copy that is in H itself. The *names* in this case are just ways to refer to the hash ID.