# Build last commit in GIT

Tags: git, github, jenkins, build, delta

I have a big project on a GIT branch and I need to do monthly release. There are only few modules update in one release but my team is doing complete build and it is taking an hour. So I am looking if their is a procedure to build only last commit.

I was reading documentation on Delta but I think that is something else. I do not have any other idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Git commit references the [all repository content anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8198276/6309).
So building the last commit would still build all modules in that rpeository.

So you would need your modules managed in their own repository in order to do a partial build of selected modules.
And your main repository could reference the same modules as [Git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), whenever you need to make a full build.