# Does git store information about the machine & folder structure related to each commit?

Tags: git

I'm wondering if for each commit git persists information related to the originating machine of each commit/push.

I've asked ChatGPT and it says that git does not store such things. But I'd like to get a second opinion.

Comment: Everything git stores in each commit is perfectly visible in... commits themselves. Read one with `git cat-file -p <hash>`. No info about any machine here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by folder structure. It just records paths and contents relative to the repo root directory. And depending on your gitconfig it may perform some newline conversions before uploading or after downloading.  Without getting too deep the main metadata it records is
timestamp, commit hash, an author username and email, a committer username and email, and if applicable that it was signed with a given certificate.

It does not store host names, or OS info, or local path information.

See here for more info:
[How does git store files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198105/how-does-git-store-files)