# git repo size due to commit binary file to multiple branches

Tags: git, hash, binaryfiles, filesize, git-filter-repo

I used [git-filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) to remove several large binary files from my git repo after migration from SVN. Now, I have to add few selected files back and was wondering what will happen to the git repo size if I add the identical 3.14MB binary file to 5 branches: Does git detect that the file has the identical hash? Does repo size grow by 3.14MB, or by 5x3.14MB?

And, similar question for text files: Does git detect if I add a copy of a text file to a different old/existing branch? What if it is slightly modified?

Comment: If the file is identical in all of these branches, there's only one blob. IF it doesn't ever change, it won't make the repo grow from that point. Modify one char inside your text file and you have a new blob in the database.

Comment: If in doubt you could always create an initial branch where you add the file and then branch out from that.

Comment: Think twice before adding a binary file because you are reproducing the same issue that cluttered your history. Can't you create a script that will download this binary from somewhere else (or a similar strategy)? or use git-lfs?

Answer (score 2):

If the file is bit for bit 100% identical, it will only exist as *blob* once in [Git's object database](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects).

You can manually run [`git hash-object path/to/file`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-hash-object) to verify yourself.

But changing a single bit in the file could cause it to require twice the size (each version is stored separately as full snapshot. Delta compression can help, but it's not guaranteed to work for every type of file/blob. [`git gc`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc) runs garbage collection and repacks the objects in your object database).

Further reading: [How does Git store files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198105/how-does-git-store-files)

Comment: Side note: Git compresses blobs. If you're committing compressed text files, decompress them and commit them as plain text. Same goes for zip files and similar archives, unzip them and commit them as files and directories.