# what does the word 'Snapshot' in Git means

Tags: git, github

As far as I have understood git the 'snapshots' refers to the state of wroking tree at various points in time. Further if we change the branch, the working tree changes and we start recording the snapshots of that working tree.

Am I correct here or there is something more to 'snapshots' in git.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, you exactly captured the meaning of `snapshot` in git.

Also, look here: [What is a git "Snapshot"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964099/what-is-a-git-snapshot)

Answer (score -1):

Snapshot is the rar, zip, tar, ...  with all the files in your branch that have been committed and pushed.  For example,  if you have ruined your project repository with the last push. You  can use the last snapshot to recover all the files

Comment: -1, in git the last commit  (HEAD^) is a snapshot of the last files in your branch that were commited and pushed. There is no need to unzip anything to get to it... (`git checkout -b HEAD^` OR  `git reset HEAD^ --hard` )